# python find the similarly with each elements of a nested list with other list, without using for loop

Tags: python, arrays, list, list-comprehension

I have a list like this

```
l=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[2,3,4],[3,5,7],[5,6,7],[6,7,8],[7,8,9]]
```

Now I have a another list,

```
l1=[3,6,9]
```

Now I want to calculate similarity with each element of l with l1 and append the similarity value to an empty list.

I could do this using following code,

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
values=[]
for i in l:
    values.append(cosine_similarity([i],[l1]))
```

Above code the results what I wanted but the execution time is huge. I am looking for some shortcuts to do this most efficiently.

Comment: Did you try making them numpy arrays and using broadcasting to compute cosine similarity? I guess sklearn should support numpy and broadcasting.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert everything to a 2D numpy array and then simply apply `cosine_similarity` once and let the shape broadcasting take care of everything

First you need to convert your data into numpy arrays

```
>>> l = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[2,3,4],[3,5,7],[5,6,7],[6,7,8],[7,8,9]])
>>> l.shape
(7, 3)
```

Similarly, you will also need to convert `l1`. Additionally you will need to reshape it into a 2D array

```
>>> l1 = np.array([3,6,9])
>>> l1.shape
(3,)
>>> l1 = l1.reshape(1, -1)
>>> l1.shape
(1, 3)
```

Now, you can easily just apply the cosine similarity function

```
cosine_similarity(l, l1)
```

This gives the resulting array as

```
array([[1.        ],
       [0.97463185],
       [0.99258333],
       [0.9974149 ],
       [0.96832966],
       [0.96337534],
       [0.95941195]])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use numpy 2D arrays rather than list. below code might help:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

l=np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[2,3,4],[3,5,7],[5,6,7],[6,7,8],[7,8,9]])

# You need to reshape your data 
l1=np.array([3,6,9]).reshape(1, -1)

def cal_cs(arr):
    # Reshaping here also
    return cosine_similarity(l1, arr.reshape(1, 3))

list(map(lambda x: cal_cs(x), l))
```

The result which I am getting is

```
[array([[1.]]),
 array([[0.97463185]]),
 array([[0.99258333]]),
 array([[0.9974149]]),
 array([[0.96832966]]),
 array([[0.96337534]]),
 array([[0.95941195]])
```

Hope this helps